# SonarQube doesn't break Jenkins build even though Quality Gate is violated

Tags: javascript, jenkins, sonarqube

We have Jenkins/SonarQube jobs for Java projects that fail if a developer does not make more than 70% of unit testing code coverage for new code. We're trying to setup the same thing for JavaScript projects.

I have put a lot of work into generating JUnit-like XML files using Karma and a plugin that I wrote for it. Anyway, when I commit new JavaScript code without unit test it doesn't break the Jenkins build. Here is the relevant part of the Jenkins job log:

```
...
07:13:37.417 INFO  - Parsing Unit Test run results in Surefire format from folder /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/frontend_common-jscheck/workspace/frontend_common/karma-reports/jstd
...
07:13:38.337 INFO  - Analysing /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/frontend_common-jscheck/workspace/frontend_common/karma-reports/lcov/lcov.txt
07:13:38.535 WARN  - Could not resolve 2 file paths in lcov.txt, first unresolved path: /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/frontend_common-jscheck/workspace/frontend_common/WebContent/js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js
...
07:13:41.962 INFO  - Load previous line hashes of: frontend_common-jscheck:WebContent/js/amp/utils/SlavaUtil.js...
...
07:13:44.427 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
07:13:44.456 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
07:13:44.459 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 52.594s
Final Memory: 20M/560M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can guess I change code in `SlavaUtil.js` and you can see that SonarQube analyzes it from the log. I included in the log the warning about not being able to find 2 files from the `lcov.txt` (one of which it was kind enough to display does exist so I don't know why it doesn't find it) but I think it's not the reason why the build doesn't fail. As you can see in the log it executes those post job classes which I think are supposed to fail the build but they don't.

Question: how to troubleshoot this issue?

---

Update:

I looked at one of the Java project Jenkins log that fails the Quality test, the relevant log looks like this:

```
10:11:43.780 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
10:11:43.798 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
10:11:43.801 ERROR - [BUILD BREAKER] Coverage on new code < 70 since previous version (4815 - 2015 Oct 23)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 21.991s
Final Memory: 18M/240M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Alert thresholds have been hit (1 times).
    at org.sonar.api.batch.BuildBreaker.fail(BuildBreaker.java:34)
    at org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker.analyseMeasures(AlertBreaker.java:57)
    at org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker.executeOn(AlertBreaker.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PostJobsExecutor.execute(PostJobsExecutor.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PostJobsExecutor.execute(PostJobsExecutor.java:61)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:135)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure
```

As can be seen from the log, it is the `AlertBreaker` that's supposed to throw the exception. I'm going to try to get the source code and run locally in debug mode, I guess. Don't see any other way to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Maybe you could start by investigate through the UI. Checking 3 things: 1. your file has been analysed and you can see it in the UI  2. See through the UI that the coverage of this file is of 0%  3. Check on the global dashboard that the percentage of coverage on new code is below 70%. Or have you already done that?

Comment: @Linda-SonarSourceTeam, I have done that. The dashboard shows unit testing code coverage more than 0 and I can drilldown into specific code that covered/or not.

Comment: @Linda-SonarSourceTeam, can you recommend how I can troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Have a look at the Jenkins Quality Gates Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quality+Gates+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

The build breaker plugin uses the quality status of your project to decide whether the build should fail or not (see [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin)).

Check your project in SQ's Web interface after running the analysis.

Is the project associated to a quality gate at all? If it isn't, plugin is working as expected.

If it is, is the project's quality gate red? If it is, then there is an issue with the build breaker plugin. If it isn't, it is working as expected.

If the quality gate reports a coverage value which isn't the one you would expect, then the problem is on the analysis side: check your setup (inclusions and all) and the version of language plugin you are using.